# Undefined control sequence. <argument> \shorttitle

Tags: titles

I've been receiving the error `Undefined control sequence. <argument> \shorttitle` with the following code:

```
\author{MyName}
\title{ThisPaper}
\date{01 Jan 2015}
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
Text
\end{document}

Is there something wrong with my packages?
Text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Which packages?

Comment: Put `\author` etc. *after* `\documentclass`. Where does `\shorttitle` occur?

Answer (score 5):

Put `\author` etc. *after* `\documentclass` - *not* before.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}
\author{MyName}
\title{ThisPaper}
\date{01 Jan 2015}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Is there something wrong with my packages?
Text
\end{document}
```

This way, you get the class's definitions of these macros and `\shorttitle` will be defined automatically when you define `\title`. If you use `\title` *before*, `amsart`'s definitions are not active and `\shorttitle` will not be defined.

Here's the definition of `\title` from `amsart.cls`:

```
\renewcommand*{\title}[2][]{\gdef\shorttitle{#1}\gdef\@title{#2}}
```

Notice the `\renewcommand` rather than `\newcommand`. The class is replacing the standard LaTeX `\title` with a definition of its own. The redefined version takes 2 arguments, rather than 1. But the first is optional. Moreover, the first argument is used to define `\shorttitle`:

```
\gdef\shorttitle{#1}
```

This means that if you say just

```
\title{Title}
```

then `Title` will be used for the title and `\shorttitle` will be defined to be nothing because the default value of the optional argument is `[]` in the `\renewcommand` line above.

But if you say `\title` *before* `\documentclass`, you get the standard LaTeX definition:

```
\def\title#1{\gdef\@title{#1}}
```

So, in this case, the title will be correctly set to `Title` but `\shorttitle` is never defined. This is a problem because `\maketitle` is used after `amsart.cls` has redefined it and it expects `\shorttitle` to be available. Hence, you get the error.

In general, very little, if anything, should go before `\documentclass`. Unless you are certain it should go before the class is loaded, assume that it either belongs in the preamble - the code after `\documentclass` and before `\begin{document}` - or in the document - the code after `\begin{document}` and before `\end{document}`.

Comment: To be fussy, that definition of `\title` is supplemented by `\edef\title{\@nx\@dblarg\@xp\@nx\csname\string\title\endcsname}`, which is a very clever trick for making `\title{Title}` equivalent to `\title[Title]{Title}` so the short title is defined to be the full one in case no optional argument is given.

Comment: @egreg I saw that, although I did not understand it. But it seemed to me that including that code might not be needed to convey the basic idea, and I was trying to tune the answer to what I guessed the OP's level of experience was based on the code in the question. Do you think I should add something about that? I just didn't want to make what is a relatively straightforward point impenetrable without compelling reason.

Comment: Having it in the comment is more than sufficient, I believe.

Comment: OK. Good. Thanks. (And thanks for the explanation.)

Answer (score 3):

`\author` etc. are LaTeX core commands, but shouldn't be used before `\documentclass`!

`\title` defines `\shorttitle` in `amsart.cls` but not in the standard classes.

Using it ahead of `\documentclass` it will never apply the `amsart.cls` definition of `\title` but the original 'core' one, so `\shorttitle` never get's defined -- and `\maketitle` uses `\shorttitle`

```
\documentclass[12pt]{amsart}

\author{MyName}
\title{ThisPaper}
\date{01 Jan 2015}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

Is there something wrong with my packages? -- No, but \verb+\title+ etc. should be used after the \verb+\documentclass+ 
Text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's the code from `amsart.cls`:

```
\def\maketitle{\par
  \@topnum\z@ % this prevents figures from falling at the top of page 1
  \@setcopyright
  \thispagestyle{firstpage}% this sets first page specifications
  \uppercasenonmath\shorttitle
  \ifx\@empty\shortauthors \let\shortauthors\shorttitle
  \else \andify\shortauthors
  \fi
  \@maketitle@hook
  \begingroup
  \@maketitle
  \toks@\@xp{\shortauthors}\@temptokena\@xp{\shorttitle}%
  \toks4{\def\\{ \ignorespaces}}% defend against questionable usage
  \edef\@tempa{%
    \@nx\markboth{\the\toks4
      \@nx\MakeUppercase{\the\toks@}}{\the\@temptokena}}%
  \@tempa
  \endgroup
  \c@footnote\z@
  \@cleartopmattertags
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain what `\verb+` means?

Comment: `\verb+...+` just outputs the text literally, i.e. `\author` as command, not what `\author` actually does!